# How to write logs for Azure function App slf4j?

Tags: azure-functions, slf4j, spring-cloud-function

I have implemented Azure Function App with Spring Cloud Functions.I am using lombok annotation @Slf4j for logging the messages, but I am not able to see my log file in azure portal. Can any one help me that how should I write logs for this application

I have tries sl4j and expecting logs to be printed in the mentioned file.

Answer (score -1):

Info about Azure Function is automatically logged to app insight. But to log info about your application to app insight, you will need to complete the setup for app insight.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-spring-boot

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-runtime-attach</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.18</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.18</version>
</dependency>
```

config applicationinsights.json

```
{
  "connectionString":"InstrumentationKey=54ba6f5c-0590-xx;IngestionEndpoint=https://centralus-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://centralus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
}
```

1st line is to use ApplicationInsights.attach();

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ApplicationInsights.attach();
        SpringApplication.run(Config.class, args);
    }
}
```

Use to log your application info:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class EchoHandler {

    @Autowired
    private Function<String, String> echo;

    @FunctionName("echo")
    public String execute(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET,
            HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        ExecutionContext context) {

        String input = request.getBody().get();

        log.error("Method echo " + input);
        
        return echo.apply(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)